# Problems with rigging mesh

Tags: animation, rigging

I am making a character in blender 2.83 and it has multiple pieces of clothing. Whenever I try to rig it, it doesn't work. How do I rig my character?[image]

Comment: Hi. Please define what "it doesn't work" means in this context. What actually happens? With that in mind, make the title of your question specific to the problem you are having and not just the general topic. Thanks.

Comment: I joined all the meshes and then parented and automatically weighted the meshes to the rig and when I try to animate only the human mesh animates not the other meshes.